# How to get the original original Default Arrangement from sorted array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the original sorted array in the else statement
My code is something like this,

```
const sortItems = (data) => {
        let priceArray = [];
        // Making an new array
        // let originalArray = productList.slice();
        let originalArray = [...productList]

        if (filteredState === true) {
            priceArray = filteredInfos;
        } else {
            priceArray = [...productList];
        }

        if (data === 'Price low - high') {
            priceArray.sort(
                (a, b) => a.discountedPriceWithDouble - b.discountedPriceWithDouble,
            );
        } else if (data === 'Price high - low') {
            priceArray.sort(
                (a, b) => b.discountedPriceWithDouble - a.discountedPriceWithDouble,
            );
        } else if (data === 'Newest') {
            // priceArray = originalArray.slice();
            priceArray.sort(
                (a, b) => new Date(b.createdDate) - new Date(a.createdDate),
            );
        } else {
            priceArray = originalArray;
        }

        setDupFilteredList(priceArray);
        setFilteredInfos(priceArray);
        setFilterModalSevenVisible(false);
        setOpenFilterList(false);
    };
```

When reading other answers from stack overflow they suggest to create a new array before sorting the original array.

So I create a new array by this method `let originalArray = [...productList]`
***But the else statement is not working, Which I intended to return to the original unsorted state***. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: please add what is not working?

Comment: If the object arrays are deeply nested you will have to deepcopy your array. Otherwise any change made to productList is made to originalArray

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is scope.

If a variable is declared with `let`, it is a local variable (can't be used outside of the brackets or in new brackets.

Use either `const` or `var` to declare the variable and use it outside of the local scope.

If this doesn't work:

Why not make two variables when declaring originalArray? If you make a duplicate with a different name, you can refer to it as your 'original list.' Here is what I'd do:

**Outside of the const func**

```js
var original = [];
```

**Inside of the const func**

```js
let originalArray = [...productList]
original = originalArray;
```

**Inside of the `else` portion**

```js
priceArray = original;
```

If this doesn't work, I don't understand the question from your description.